# JavaFX how use Image and ImageView to open and image from my system

Tags: javafx

I am trying to display an image using Image and ImageView classes of JavaFX and it does not work.

```
try {
  String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
  final File f = new File(workingDir, "src/chk.hrn.nye.movieplayer/img.png");
  // System.out.println(workingDir);
  // File file = new File(loadImage.class.getResource("img1.jpg").toString());
  Image img = new Image(f.toURI().toString());
  ImageView imv = new ImageView(img);
  Group root = new Group();
  root.getChildren().add(imv);
  Scene scene = new Scene(root);
  primaryStage.setScene(scene);
  primaryStage.show();
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: try a System.out.println(f) and check if the file exists in your local filesystem. Normally class.getResource("imageFile") will work

Comment: f.exist() returns true if file exists - anyway, could you tell a bit more than doesn't work? is an exception thrown, or view shows empty?